# Why do headers and footers follow movement of row when deleting it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm building an app in Swift that relies heavily upon Table Views. It uses both headers and footers, as well as row deletion. For some strange reason when I perform a row deletion, the header and footer follows the sliding movement of the row to be deleted. The below screenshots explain what I mean.

[image]

**How do you avoid this?**

I'm implementing the delete function like this:

```
// Deleting
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // Handling data source updating, cell row deletion, transition...

    }
}
```

And the header and footer like this:

```
// ## Header ##
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("shoppingHeader") as! ShoppingTableViewHeaderCell

    // Clear up startup background
    headerCell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // Add covering background color
    headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x22b8a3, alpha: 1)

    // Set store image, or store title if image is unavailable
    let url = NSURL(string: dataSource[sortedStores[section]]["meta_data"]["logo"].string!)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    if data != nil { // Store image
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        headerCell.imageView?.image = imageResize(image: image!, cellWidth: 90, cellHeight: 30)
    } else { // Store name label
        headerCell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[sortedStores[section]]["meta_data"]["nameStore"].string
        headerCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 16)
        headerCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    // Right hand side details: define strings
    let address = dataSource[sortedStores[section]]["meta_data"]["street"].string
    let distanceMeasure = dataSource[sortedStores[section]]["meta_data"]["distance"].int!
    let numberOfOffers = dataSource[sortedStores[section]]["offers"].count

    // Right hand side details: assign strings to variables
    headerCell.rightLabel0.text = address
    headerCell.rightLabel1.text = "\(distanceMeasure) m away"
    if numberOfOffers == 1 {
        headerCell.rightLabel2.text = "1 offer available"
    } else {
        headerCell.rightLabel2.text = "\(numberOfOffers) offers available"
    }

    // Right hand side details: set text color
    headerCell.rightLabel0.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerCell.rightLabel1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerCell.rightLabel2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return headerCell
}


// ## Footer ##
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("shoppingFooter") as! UITableViewCell

    // Set black color to show that footer moves too.
    footerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() //clearColor()

    return footerCell
}
```

Comment: how do you create your headers an footers?

Comment: @VladimirKravchenko I'm adding the code as per protocol. I think... I updated the question, to include this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using reusable cells for headers and footers is your problem. Try to use nibs instead. Create a separate .xib files for header and footer cells. And get your cell with:

```
let headerCell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("YourNibName", owner: self, options: nil).first as! ShoppingTableViewHeaderCell
```

Or implement a UITableViewHeaderFooterView's subclass, create a nib for it, register this nib with:

```
 tableView .registerNib(UINib(nibName:"YourNibName", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "TableHeader")
```

And get your header's view with:

```
let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("TableHeader")
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What is my nib file in this context? I haven't used nibs before, all I know is that it is something important related to the graphics of my interface.

Comment: Well, using nibs is not needed but at least `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` would be probably preferred.

Comment: Sulthan gave you a good advice. You can follow this post http://iosdev12.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-set-custom-section-header-in.html

Comment: @Sulthan this throws me a runtime error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) "

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it. Thanks for the help! I will accept the answer if I make it work properly.

Answer (score 7):

Simply return `headerCell.contentView` instead of `headerCell` and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: but the click event is not working when use this trick Any further help for that